# First GPS location and inserting it into database slows down the android app

Tags: c#, android, mysql, xamarin, gps

I am building an android app which is supposed to use GPS for getting location and then location is inserted into database. Everytime location is found and it is supposed to be inserted into database, app slows down and the notification comes out: App is not responding. Would you like to exit? etc. (this especially happens when the first location is found).

These are the ways how I tried to make insertion into database in order to avoid lagging:

**1.**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("...");
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

parameters.Add("...","...");
parameters.Add...

try
{
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    client.UploadValuesAsync(uri,"POST",parameters);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Debug("ERROR",ex.Message);
}
```

**2.**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("...");
string responseString = string.Empty;
var postData = "...=" + ...;
postData += ...;

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

try
{

     using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
     {
           stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
     }

     var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Log.Debug("ERROR",ex.Message);
}
```

Both ways have the same result: app is lagging. What can I do to prevent this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have a background service which is getting location and sending it with broadcast receiver to foreground. When the location is received in foreground (i.e. in activity) I am calling method which sends location to web service (that is written in PHP). PHP script inserts posted values to database.

Comment: You're probably trying to do this on the Main UI thread, try to use AsyncTask. Android docs; https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: What are then `UploadValuesAsync()` and `UploadValuesTaskAsync()` methods in `WebClient` used for?

Comment: `it is supposed to be inserted into database, ` Sorry but cant you inform us better? You are posting data to a webserver on the internet. Not inserting data to a locat database on the device.

Comment: Sorry for wrong expressing.

Comment: @DevMan         i'm not known with said methods, so I wouldn't know if they handle that for you. but we really would need more information on what you exactly try to do and where this code is used, before we could help you.

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: Any has a suggestion?

Comment: You might need to await the call to `client.UploadValuesAsync(uri,"POST",parameters);`. Async/await best practices dictate that all calls to `...Async` methods should be awaited. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx